# Why is my file structure location incorrect

Tags: css, file

I have a file called home.css that I want to assign a background image in:

```
background-img: url(".../my-img.jpg");
```

However, I'm getting errors that the file cannot be located due to the file location declared. I thought I got the correct amount of "..." but maybe not? Can anybody spot what's wrong considering the file structure below:

```
App
  home-app
    home
      home.css
Assets
  Images
    banner.jpg
```

Comment: `...` is not a thing. It's `./` or `../` or an arbitrary number of `../../`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every "../" = one catalog up, so if you want to get in "Images" then href should looks like: background-img: url('../../../Assets/Images/my-img.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

use background-img: url("/Assets/Images/my-img.jpg"); it will work in any where.